# Is it possible to include other documents from the same collection in MongoDB's aggregate() function?

Tags: mongodb

Specifically, I want to implement moving average and similar calculations, that need data from other documents from within a set time frame relative to the current document's timestamp, and was wondering if it is possible to do that with `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As at MongoDB 2.4, the Aggregation Framework does not support fetching additional documents into a pipeline or referencing documents relative to the current document.  You will have to implement these sort of calculations in your application logic.

You may want to upvote and watch [SERVER-4437](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4437) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker; this feature suggestion is to add support for windowing operations on pipelines.